# Populate Dropdown from Zoho Response

Tags: php, arrays, json, zoho, zohobooks

I am trying to populate a dropdown from the ZOHO API response I am getting with my request. I have two files. request.php and zoho.php.

I am receiving the response from request.php as below.

```
object(stdClass)#2 (4) {
  ["code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["message"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["invoices"]=>
  array(200) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (54) {
      ["invoice_id"]=>
      string(19) "2163791000003899301"
    }
  }
}
```

in order to get the result I am decoding the object as below

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$decode_data = json_decode($result);
var_dump($decode_data);
```

I am having a popup in zoho.php.

```
<select value="Select Zoho Invoice" name="zohoinvoice" id="zohoinvoice" class="SlectBox form-control">
   <?php echo zohoFunc(); ?>
</select>


function zohoFunc(){
   global $decode_data;
   $output='';
   $output .= '<option value = "Select Invoice">Select Invoice</option>';
   foreach($decode_data as $inv){
     $output[] .= '<option value = "'.$inv[0]->invoice_id.'">'.$inv[0]->invoice_number.'</option>';
   }
   return $output;
}
```

The way I am looping the data I have received is below. I am trying to get as the way how we populate a dropdown from SQL which is a string and zoho's case its an array. Where I am making the mistake?

Comment: How many times exactly do you expect a foreach over the _empty_ array `$decode_data = array();` to iterate ...?

Comment: please check the updated. it should be a global variable.

Comment: And have you verified it actually contains what you think it should, in that place?

Comment: yes it contains.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241571/populate-json can you please join @CBroe

Comment: Then I don't see what the problem is supposed to be. What result are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer gave me an idea to loop through the result on zoho.php itself and get the value to dropdown HTML.

```
function zohoFunc(){
        global $decode_data;
        global $result;
        $output='';
        $output.= '<option value = "Select Invoice">Select Invoice</option>';
        foreach($decode_data['invoices'] as $result) {
            $invoice_number = $result['invoice_number'];
            $_invoiceReturn .= '<option value = "'.$invoice_number.'">'.$invoice_number.'</option>';
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You you are looking for all the invoices in your data set. So try.

```
foreach($decode_data->invoices  as $myCurrentInvoice) {
    echo $myCurrentInvoice->invoice_id;
    echo '<br>';
    //$output[] .= '<option value = "'.$myCurrentInvoice->invoice_id.'">'.$myCurrentInvoice->invoice_number.'</option>';
    
}
```